# Get rows from a SELECT sql statement

Tags: sql, objective-c, sqlite

I have a database, and i do a S ELECT statement on SQL for 10 random rows.
It's for Iphone App, so Objective C.

How could i get back the information after the statement ?

```
...
 const char *sql3 = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT id FROM tabledesquestions ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 10"] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    sqlite3_stmt *sql1Statement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare(database1, sql3, -1, &sql1Statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement");
    }

while (sqlite3_step(sql1Statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {

     numeroqdonnee = sqlite3_column_int(sql1Statement, 0);
       }
```

For now, i get back info just for the first row. How could i get back the info (id) for the others rows.

```
I would like something like that 
numeroqdonnee2 =
numeroqdonnee3 =
numeroqdonnee4 =
...
```

Many thanks

Comment: Please use the proper tags for your question. This question is about sqlite, not mysql or sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the results to some array:

```
const char *sql3 = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT id FROM tabledesquestions ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 10"] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];

sqlite3_stmt *sql1Statement;
int returnCode;
if(sqlite3_prepare(database1, sql3, -1, &sql1Statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database1));
}
else 
{
    while ((returnCode = sqlite3_step(sql1Statement)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        numeroqdonnee = sqlite3_column_int(sql1Statement, 0);
        [results addObject:@(numeroqdonnee)];
    }
    if (returnCode != SQLITE_DONE)
        NSLog(@"Problem with step statement: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database1));

    sqlite3_finalize(sql1Statement);
}

// now do whatever you want with this results array

NSLog(@"results = %@", results);

// or

[results enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"numeroqdonnee%d = %d", idx, [obj integerValue]);
}];
```

Or you could just log the results directly:

```
const char *sql3 = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT id FROM tabledesquestions ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 10"] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

sqlite3_stmt *sql1Statement;
int returnCode;
if(sqlite3_prepare(database1, sql3, -1, &sql1Statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database1));
}
else 
{
    while ((returnCode = sqlite3_step(sql1Statement)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        numeroqdonnee = sqlite3_column_int(sql1Statement, 0);
        NSLog(@"numeroqdonnee = %d", numeroqdonnee);
    }
    if (returnCode != SQLITE_DONE)
        NSLog(@"Problem with step statement: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database1));

    sqlite3_finalize(sql1Statement);
}
```

Note, I'd suggest you log the `sqlite3_errmsg` if you have any problems (otherwise you're just flying blind). I've also added the `sqlite3_finalize` (which your original code sample may have had, but I just wanted to make sure).

Comment: Many thanks. I learn a litte bit more about dictionary and arrays... thanks u again for ur time